# Android: How to Update a component of Custom ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a custom listview with custom adapter. The custom listview consists of image and two textviews lets say textViewA and textViewB. Now i want to change the text of textViewB in every row of custom listview without updating other components. My first question is it possible? If yes then how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing a `String[]` argument to your adapter? Something like:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  String[] data_text;

  CustomAdapter() {

  }

  CustomAdapter(String[] text) {
      data_text = text;
  }

  CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> text) {

      data_text = new String[text.size()];

  for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
      data_text[i] = text.get(i);
   }

  }

  @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return data_text.length;
  }

  @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
      return null;
  }

  @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
  }

  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
      View row;

      row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);

      TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);

      textview.setText(data_text[position]);

   return (row);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must call  notifyDataSetChanged() and change textview's value in your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setadaptor(null);
// do what ever methods here to change your data, strings objects, etc
listview.notifyDataSetChanged();
```